# How do I get a list of all the last modified tables in an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, timestamp, last-modified, sql-timestamp

```
select ora_rowscn from table_name;
```

`ORA_ROWSCN` returns the conservative upper bound system change number (SCN) of the most recent change to the row. This pseudocolumn is useful for determining approximately when a row was last updated.

How do I get the timestamp from here? Also, is there any query by which I can get all the last modified tables in a particular schema?

Answer (score 2):

`SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` takes as an argument a number that evaluates to a system change number (SCN), and returns the approximate timestamp associated with that SCN.

```
SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) 
FROM employees
WHERE employee_id = 188;
```

If you have 10g or above, you can use Oracle's flashback functionality to get this information. You would need to enable flashback;

```
select  table_name ,max(commit_timestamp) 
from FLASHBACK_TRANSACTION_QUERY 
where table_owner = 'YOUR_SCHEMA' 
      and operation in ('INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE','MERGE') 
group by table_name
```

Comment: Note you need priveleges  to run FLASHBACK_TRANSACTION_QUERY

Answer (score 2):

There should be no need to get involved with SCNs for what you are asking.  Why not just:

```
begin dbms_stats.flush_database_monitoring_info; end;

select * from dba_tab_modifications
where timestamp >= sysdate - 7
order by timestamp desc;
```

Unless you are (foolishly?) running with only `BASIC` statistics level (default is `TYPICAL`, which is higher), this should work fine in any 11g database or later.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, could have been specific and a little filtered and sorted. 

SELECT
    Table_Owner,
    Table_Name,
    Timestamp,
    Inserts,
    Updates,
    Deletes
FROM
    Dba_Tab_Modifications
WHERE
        Timestamp >= Sysdate - 15
    AND Upper(Table_Owner) IN ( 'SCHEMA1', 'SCHEMA2', 'SCHEMA3' )
ORDER BY
    1,
    3 DESC;